# Magento Cron jobs: Log cleaning and reindexing

Tags: magento, cron

How to setup cron job for log cleaning and re-indexing in Magento? I setup cron job for cron.php and its running but it does not seem that log has been cleared because when I looked into my table "log_url" it is sill has the same data which was in this table before cron running, also even in the "cron_sechedule " table there is a success message against Newsletter and some other but I can not see "Log Cleaning" and "reindexing" success message. On Magento website [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)

they said that logcleaning and reindexing is commented out in the code so in which file I can un-comment to setup cron job fo log cleaning and reindexing?

Comment: Contact your host support or review the help document to set your cron job file path. Some time direct file path doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember particularly but you should add cron.sh or cron.php file to your OS cronjob.

**UPDATE 1**

So the problem isn't with cron jobs itself but wih log cleaning mechanism.

As for DB cleaning I have following snippet which might be useful for you:

```
    private function cleanLog(){
        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

        $write->query("TRUNCATE log_customer");
        $write->query("TRUNCATE log_quote");
        $write->query("TRUNCATE log_summary");
        $write->query("TRUNCATE log_summary_type");
        $write->query("TRUNCATE log_url");
        $write->query("TRUNCATE log_url_info");
        $write->query("TRUNCATE log_visitor");
        $write->query("TRUNCATE log_visitor_info");
        $write->query("TRUNCATE report_event");

    }
```

Comment: I have added cron.php to my OS cronjob

Comment: Have you tested it? For example by mail function? Just wondering.

Comment: Yeah I have tested this I am receiving failure messages in case of failure and in case of success I am not receiving any messages.

Comment: If you have cache turn on, it might be that your config with cron job isn't in cache.

Comment: Yeah cache is turned on, do I need to turn off cache?

Comment: Hm try to clean it. So Flush magento cache or flush cache storage. It might be it, but I am not sure.

Comment: Does I only need to setup cron.php as cron job then it will automatically run all cron jobs and reindex all is also available in the default cron that is run if cron.php is running as cron OR I have to set a separate cron for rexindexall?

Comment: Well, I am not sure, as I worked with crons only once, with newsletters. Then i'v simply put corn.php to run every 2 minutes and voila. So I guess there should be only 1 OScron in setup. But I suggest you to turn off caching and test various variants.

Comment: Its not working even I changed the XML file and add cron schedule but it did not worked, then I will separately call shell/log.php like this php -f httpdocs/shell/log.php clean I received email with "Log Cleaned" but records are still in the all log tables in the database. Any one who has experience with cron job setting in magento for re-indexing all and log cleaning?